# Google app scripts proj4js library integration

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, proj4js

Good people of stackoverflow.

I would like to write a custom function in google sheets for coordinate transformation. The function shuld transform coordinates in Slovene natioanl grid (EPSG: 3912) to WGS84 (EPSG: 4326). I think that this could be elegantly done with [proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) library.

But since I am complety new to javascript and Google app scripts I am wondering if it is possible to import a library to app scripts. I found out that proj4js is hosted on [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/proj4js) and could be directly used in browser applications but I dont know how to import it in Google app scripts.

I tried to add this library by Script ID, where I used the [proj4js cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/proj4js) links as Script ID but I got an error: "Unable to look up library. Check the ID and access permissions and try again."

I would be really gratefull if anybody could help me overcome this rookie obstacle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch the content from the library URL with [UrlFetchApp.fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)), and evaluate the retrieved content with [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

You can then use this library.

#### Code sample:

```
const libraryUrl = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.3/proj4.min.js";
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(libraryUrl).getContentText());
proj4(...);
```